# Momentum equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

PLEASE HELP:
I am trying to calculate how seatbelts change momentum in the case of a car accident. Basically trying to prove how a seatbelt helps when you get in an accident. The image shows what I have written so far, but I am stuck. [image]

Comment: The seatbelts do not change the force on you, they stop you from flying forward and hitting the steering wheel and windscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum of the car is irrelevant. The car would only transfer momentum to the person in the case of the car hitting the person. The relevant variables are the momentum of the **person** and the forces acting on the person.

The seatbelt is stationary with respect to the car, which is very suddenly stationary with respect to the tree. Your body still wants to move at the pre-collision velocity.

Your torso slams into the seatbelt. The seatbelt has some stretch to it - not much, or it would be useless, but a little. Your torso also has some give to it and can be compressed fairly significantly without life-threatening injury. The seatbelt is fairly broad, so it does that squishing over a fairly wide area.

The amount that the seatbelt stretches, plus the amount that your torso squishes, gives you the stopping distance. Call this d. Seatbelts are designed so that this distance is about 30cm.

Your initial velocity was v. Assuming that the stretchiness and squishiness of everything involved in a given collision is roughly invariant with how much it is stretched or squished, we can approximate $t = d/v$.

Power per unit area is what causes injury in blunt-force trauma. Basically, a given material (say, bone) has a particular maximum amount of energy it can handle at once before it breaks, tears, or otherwise loses its shape irreversibly. The more you can spread out the impact in space or time, the less injury will result.

The energy dissipated in the collision between you and the now-stationary car is your kinetic energy before impact, $T=mv^2$. So the power dissipated by your body is $P = \frac{T}t = \frac{mv^2}{d/v} = \frac{mv^3}d$. By increasing $d$, the seatbelt decreases the power dissipated by your body while at the same time spreading it out over the whole area of the seatbelt. The power per unit area is still large and will cause major bruising, but is unlikely to cause permanent injury.

However, consider the case without the seatbelt. The car stops and your body keeps going forward. Now instead of a stretchy seatbelt dissipating $T=mv^2$ through your squishy body over a distance of $d$ and spreading it out over the area of a seatbelt, a rock-hard windshield and steering wheel are dissipating that energy through your body and head over a much smaller distance and a much smaller surface area. Consequently, the power per unit area is much higher. On top of that, a lot of it is being dissipated through your head and neck, which are much more fragile than your torso. Death and permanent injury are likely.